# How do I change the home page to the registered user's profile page

Tags: redirect, homepage, users

I have a custom profile page for my users.  I need to have wordpress redirect the homepage to the user's profile page if they are logged in.  If they are not logged in or registered, wordpress would show the normal home page.

My homepage url string would look like this for logged in users: `http://my_site.com/user/some_user`  ... with of course "some_user" being called up as the logged in user's user name.

I've been trying to piece together bits of code I've found on this site but nothing has worked so far.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Try using this plugin: [Peter's Login Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/)

Comment: I've tried Peter's Login Redirect.. It doesn't work because it doesn't allow me to dynamically change the page it's redirecting to based on user.

Comment: You need to break your problem down into easier smaller problems, e.g. "How do I test if a user is logged in" or "How do I redirect a user from one page to another?"

Answer (score 1):

Check that your are [on the home page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home), and that the [user is logged in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in), and redirect if both are true:

```
function redir_user_wpse_187622() {
  if (is_home() && is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    wp_safe_redirect(get_author_posts_url( $user_id));
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redir_user_wpse_187622');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm a novice and want to make sure I understand... I'm guessing I put this somewhere on my functions.php file and then call up the function on my header.php page?  is that right?

Comment: You can put the whole thing in `functions.php`. No need to "call" anything. That is what the `add_action()` is for.

Comment: Thanks again, that helps. I'm almost there... so I'm also guessing that I need to swap out 'abc' to the page I'm wanting to redirect to, I'm just not sure how to code the string to bring in the user name at the end of the url string.  for that line I've unsuccessfully tried this:  wp_safe_redirect(home_url() . '/user/' . wp_get_current_user()->ID );

Comment: @Sam: See the edit.

Comment: Still didn't work. is there anyway I can see what url string this code is putting out? Just to recap; i have to get the following url: "mysite.com/user/user_name"
I've been trying other things and finally got the following code to work if I add it to my header.php at the very top.  I just don't want this to be hard coded to the page and would rather have it part of functions:

Comment: <?php if(is_front_page()) {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $newURL = home_url() . '/user/' . get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', wp_get_current_user()->ID ); 
   header('Location: '.$newURL);
    }
} ?>

Comment: @Sam this code redirects to the author archive page, which is what you should be using to build your profile page. Your responses imply instead that you've used a page and a custom page template. If so you'll need to replaced the `get_author_posts_url` part with code to grab the permalink of that page ( or do things the recommended way ). If you don't know how to do that, I recommend creating a new question with *"How do I get the permalink of a page if I know it's slug?"*